# Calling Web api controller from view in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I want to call web api controller from view by passing different parammeters.

Here is the code of the controller.

```
public samplecontroller:webapicontroller

{

}
```

If i call the controller with the following URL `http://localhost/api/samplecontroller/1/2/3`

1,2,3 are the parameters .I want to know how to write a method inside the controller to accept these parameters and for further processing.

Comment: Actually i am using an applet to call the we api controller.http://localhost/api/samplecontroller/1/2/3
is actually the url output from the applet .I am able to call the controller but I dont know how to map the ids i.e., id1=1 ,id2=2 to the method inside the controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to automatically map URL path segments to parameters in your action you can use routing to define how that mapping happens. There's a tutorial available here: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api

In your case you could have a route like so:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
  name: "My custom route",
  routeTemplate: "api/sample/{part1}/{part2}/{part3}"
);
```

Then you could have this action method:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string part1, string part2, string part3) {
   ...
}
```